# DataGridTextColumn ValidationRule with parameter hibernateConnector not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validationrules, datagridtextcolumn

I try to implement a ValidationRule for a `DataGridTextColumn` that should test the nullability against a NHibernate property.
The check is actually done within my `HibernateConnector.isNullable(String className, String propertyName)` method.
Therefore the HibernateConnector has to be passed to the ValidationRule.

The below referenced mynamespace.TeamsForm.xaml.cs has `public HibernateConnector hibernateConnector { get; set; }`

Since I'm pretty new to WPF/XAML I implemented it using https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31422.wpf-passing-a-data-bound-value-to-a-validation-rule.aspx as an example.

**Wrapper class**

```
public class HibernateConnectionWrapper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HibernateConnectorProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("hibernateConnector", typeof(HibernateConnector),
         typeof(HibernateConnectionWrapper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public HibernateConnector hibernateConnector
    {
        get { return (HibernateConnector)GetValue(HibernateConnectorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HibernateConnectorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Binding proxy**

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

**The validation class**

```
public class EditRueckennummerValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public HibernateConnectionWrapper Wrapper { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        bool n = Wrapper.hibernateConnector.isNullable(typeof(SpielerImTeam).FullName, "Rueckennummer");
        // ... more code
```

**The relevant XAML sections**

```
<rcappbase:AbstractWorkAreaForm x:Class="mynamespace.TeamsForm"
  ...  
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <BindingProxy Data="{Binding}" x:Key="proxy"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<!-- other elements -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="rueckennummer" IsReadOnly="False" DisplayIndex="5" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Rueckennummer" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:EditRueckennummerValidationRule>
                    <local:EditRueckennummerValidationRule.Wrapper>
                        <mynamespaceandassembly:HibernateConnectionWrapper  hibernateConnector="{Binding Path=Data.hibernateConnector, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                    </local:EditRueckennummerValidationRule.Wrapper>
                </local:EditRueckennummerValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>  
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
<!-- more elements -->
```

I can compile and run the code, but in `EditRueckennummerValidationRule.Validate(...)` at `Wrapper.hibernateConnector.isNullable(...)` **hibernateConnector is null**.

So what am I doing wrong here ?
Has it to do with the BindingProxy (all examples that I saw apparently have the same code) ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a while to get understanding to "Data context" but think I meanwhile solved my own question:

I moved

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <BindingProxy Data="{Binding}" x:Key="proxy"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

to

```
<rcappbase:AbstractWorkAreaForm.Resources>
    <BindingProxy Data="{Binding }" x:Key="proxy"/>
</rcappbase:AbstractWorkAreaForm.Resources>
```

and added a line to

```
public TeamsForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; // <-- !!!! set the data context
}
```

This line I had missed from the example referenced above!
Now `Wrapper.hibernateConnector` is set when it comes to validation.